# jQuery.getJSON is outputting additional copies of JSON contents. and $.toggle dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is jQuery.append necessary for what I want to do if not then how can I do this with out using append? **And I don't want to use append because it makes copies of json outputs** I just want to use a toggle button to hide and show the JSON results with a button. And I don't want to have the JSON results to output copies more than once. I assume that stackoverflow.com don't have a ajax

editor to show you this so I know the perfect editor you guys can use to show me how to do this. My code example is based on exactly on this example but mines have toggle attach to it but It failed. So here's the

AJAX editor [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_getjson)
And here's my failed attempt code example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ").toggle();
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the JSON object code that is used in mine and w3schools [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js).

```
{ 
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 25
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('div').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div style="display:none"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can I do this with out append I found out it  isn't necessary to use append.

Comment: and I don't want to use append because it makes copies of json outputs I don't want any copies of json data just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, what I have done is added `empty()` so that the `div` you are trying to append the data is set to empty i.e, `$('div').empty();` just before append is used.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").hide();
$("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
    $('div').empty();
        $.each(result, function(i, field){

            $("div").append(field + " ").toggle();
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: how can I do this with out append I found out it  isn't necessary to use append.

Comment: and I don't want to use append because it makes copies of json outputs I don't want any copies of json data just saying.

Comment: do you mean that your data is repeated after every click and there are multiple output?

Comment: Yes sorry I should made that clear but after a few mins playing around with the examples here I found out append makes copies of the same JSON data and I don't want that .

Comment: did you try the above code? It doesn't copy the data every time the button is clicked. calling `empty()` before will clear the previous data

Comment: yes I did I love it but I don't want append in that code if that's possible I'm trying to stay away from append.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var data = { 
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 25
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        //$.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
            $.each(data, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ").toggle();
            });
        //});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Because JSON File you are loading is not available.

Comment: how can I do this with out append I found out it  isn't necessary to use append.

Comment: and I don't want to use append because it makes copies of json outputs I don't want any copies of json data just saying.

Comment: so what you want exactly? What is your scenario?

Comment: Basically output the json data normally with out copies being out putted I just don't want an army of the same json outputs I only need one output of that Json data. So when I press the button to show the json output  I want to be able to press the same button to hide the json output.

Comment: means you want to hide old data and append new data?

Comment: I know I just don't want that in my code tho people tell me there is many ways to get the same result in coding so I know it's possible to do this with out append I just want to stay away from append and my friend asked a question here with out using append and they gave him an answer not including append but sadly that example was based on using $.each to out put a basic js object and no Ajax was used in that example so in this situation I want to do the something similar here but with Ajax and the $.getJason comand.

Comment: still didn't get you what you want to change in existing code??? or it is totaly wrong? or should i delete it?